# How to append data attribute value in p tag dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

"<div class="text" data-name="test1"> </div>"
  <div class="text" data-name="test1"> </div>
  <div class="text" data-name="test1"> </div>
  <div class="text" data-name="test1"> </div>
  <div class="text" data-name="test1"> </div>

append should like this

<div class="text"> <p>test 1</p></div>
  <div class="text"> <p>test 2</p></div>

Comment: your question is not clear.  Do you want to do with this JS / PHP?  Where is the data coming from etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('div.text').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.append($('<p>').html($this.data('name')));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of transforming the elements.

```js
$('div[data-name]').each(function() {
  var data = $(this).data("name");
  $(this).removeAttr( "data-name" );
  data = data.slice(0, 4) + " " + data.slice(4);
  $(this).append("<p>" + data);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text" data-name="test1"> </div>
<div class="text" data-name="test1"> </div>
<div class="text" data-name="test1"> </div>
<div class="text" data-name="test1"> </div>
<div class="text" data-name="test1"> </div>
```